# Usin ajax request on php MVC

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am making a game site in php and javascript. So my classes and my data are in php and I encode them in json datatype. I call my view which itself calls the js file which, thanks to the ajax request, recovers the php data encoded in json and post them with javascript. My problem is that I don't know how to integrate this into my mvc, ie, go through my index with an action and not call my view directly.

My controller :

```
class Controlleur
{
    public function __construct() {
        global $rep,$vues;

        try{
            $action=$_REQUEST['action'];
            switch($action){
                case NULL:
                    $this->homePage();
                    break;
                case "VoirScore":
                    $this->afficherScore();
                    break;
                default:
                    $dVueEreur[] =  "Erreur d'appel php";
                    require ($rep.$vues['error']);
                    break;
            }

        } catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            $dVueEreur[] =  "Erreur inattendue PDO!!! ";
            require ($rep.$vues['error']);

        }
        catch (Exception $e2)
        {
            $dVueEreur[] =  "Erreur inattendue!!! ";
            require ($rep.$vues['error']);
        }
    }

    public function homePage(){
        global $vues, $rep;

        require($rep . $vues['homePage']);
    }
```

My index :

```
session_start();

Autoload::charger();

new Controlleur();
```

My Js ajax request :

```
var Game = {
    cards: [],
    selected: [],
    score: 0,
    $board: $('[data-display="game-board"]'),
    $score: $('[data-display="score"]'),



    deal: function() {
        var self = this;
        var dealRequest = $.ajax({
            url: 'set.php?action=deal',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                self.cards = data;
                self.displayCards.call(self);
                self.setCardListeners();
                self.setPageListeners();
            }
        }); },
```

If u need more explication or more details you can just teel me.

Comment: Just because you call one of your classes "controller" does not make it MVC.

Answer (score 0):

This is the view homePage who call the other views and set.js is the file that integrated the javascript file with ajax and u can see i call her without an action.

```
 <div class="menu box">
        <a href="#" class="logo">HyperSet</a>
        <a href="set.html">Jouer</a>
        <a href="index.php?action=VoirScore">Voir Les Scores</a>
        <a href="#">Règles</a>

    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vues/js/Settings.js"></script>
```

This is my set.html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>(TEST) Set</h1>
    <p>Find sets.</p>
    <p>Sets found:  <span data-display="score" class="score">0</span></p>
    <p>Number of Sets:  <span data-display="nbSets" class="nbSets"></span></p>

    <div class="game-board" data-display="game-board" style="display: block;" ></div>
</div>


</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vues/js/set.js"></script>
```